# How to un- or re-installe TortoiseGit on windows 10?

Tags: windows, git, tortoisegit

My TortoiseGit 1.8.7 fails to work since the last update of Windows 10. However, I tried to install te the latest 2.1.0 but this fails because it cannot close and restart my Windows Explorer, while also uninstalling the 1.8.7 in Control Panel fails because 'a DLL from the installer package could not be run'.

How do I approach this problem best ?

Comment: Maybe https://tortoisegit.org/issue/1909 helps, also you can try to start TortoiseGit 2.1 installer and then kill explorer.exe with taskmanager manually, run the install, and resatrt explorer.exe with taskmanager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same issue as stated in https://tortoisegit.org/issue/1909:

Its required to reinstall/repair the [Microsoft C++ 2012 Update 4 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679).